# Trying to hook into AngularJS ng-show with JavaScript Greensock Animation

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, gsap

> Hello,
>
> I am very new to working with AngularJS.
>
> I have a basic modal working where I am using ui-router to transition the view inside a bootstrap modal using ui-view within the modal-body. I also have previous and next buttons that correctly appear and dissappear in the footer based on the page you are currently on inside the modal. These buttons also navigate you to the next or previous page in the modal.
>
> What I would like to do is the following:
>
> 1) hook into ng-show so that when true, my buttons will fade in and when false they fade out
>
> 2) also, the view-container height is collapsing. Is there an angular way to set the height according to the contents of ui-view?

PLEASE NOTE THAT THE PLUNKER LINK BELOW IS A BETTER DEMONSTRATION OF MY PROBLEM.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router", "ngAnimate"]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
 .state("step1", {
  url: "/step1",
  templateUrl: "step1.html"
 })
 .state("step2", {
  url: "/step2",
  templateUrl: "step2.html"

 })
 .state("step3", {
  url: "/step3",
  templateUrl: "step3.html"

 });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})

app.controller("appController", ["$scope", "$location", function($scope, $location) {
 $scope.clickJoin = function($state) {
   $location.path("step1");
   showHidePrevNextBtns();
 }
 
 $scope.clickNext = function($state) {
  if($location.path() === "/step2") {
    $location.path("step3");
  }
  if($location.path() === "/step1") {
    $location.path("step2");
  } 
  showHidePrevNextBtns();
 };
 
 $scope.clickPrevious = function($state) {
  if($location.path() === "/step2") {
   $location.path("step1");
  }
  if($location.path() === "/step3") {
   $location.path("step2");
  }
  showHidePrevNextBtns();
 };
 
 function showHidePrevNextBtns() {
  if($location.path() === "/step2" || $location.path() === "/step3") $scope.previousBtn = true;
  else $scope.previousBtn = false;

  if($location.path() === "/step1" || $location.path() === "/step2") $scope.nextBtn = true;
  else $scope.nextBtn = false;
 }
}]);

app.animation(".view-animation", viewAnimation);
app.animation(".fade", fadeAnimation);

function viewAnimation() {
  return {
    enter: function(element, done) {
      var tl = new TimelineMax()
  .set(element, {autoAlpha: 0, x: 100})
        .to(element, 0.5, {autoAlpha: 1, x: 0, ease:Power1.easeInOut})
        .add(done);
    },
    
    leave: function(element, done) {
      var tl = new TimelineMax()
        .to(element, 0.5, {autoAlpha: 0, x: -100, ease:Power1.easeInOut})
        .add(done);
    }
  };
}

function fadeAnimation() {
  return {
    enter: function(element, done) {
      var tl = new TimelineMax()
        .set(element, {autoAlpha: 0 })
        .to(element, 0.5, {autoAlpha: 1})
        .add(done);
    },
    
    leave: function(element, done) {
      var tl = new TimelineMax()
  .set(element, {autoAlpha: 1 })
        .to(element, 0.5, {autoAlpha: 0})
        .add(done);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.view-container {
  position: relative;
}

.view-animation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#status-buttons div { 
 color:#FFF; 
 display:inline-block; 
 font-size:12px; 
 margin-right:10px; 

 text-transform:uppercase; 
}

#status-buttons span{ 
 color:#000000; 
 display:inline-block; 
 font-size:12px; 
 margin-right:10px; 

 text-transform:uppercase; 
 
 background:#ffffff; display:block; height:30px; margin:0 auto 10px; padding-top:5px; width:30px; 
    border-radius:50%; 
}

#status-buttons span.active   { 
 background-color:#C32026; 
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">

 <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
   
  <div class="btn-group dropdown">
   <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinModal" ng-click="clickJoin()"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Join</button>
  </div>
          
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="joinModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" >
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title italic" id="myModalLabel">Become a Member Today!</h4>
     </div>
             
     <!-- NAVIGATION -->
     <div class="page-header text-center" >
      <h2>Step</h2>
      <div id="status-buttons">
       <div><span class="active">1</span></div>
       <div><span>2</span></div>
       <div><span>3</span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
             
     <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="view-container">
       <div class="view-animation" ui-view></div>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     <br />
     
     <br />
     <br />
             
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
       <button type="button" id="previousBtn" ng-show="previousBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="clickPrevious()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
       <button type="button" id="nextBtn" ng-show="nextBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="clickNext()">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
       <button type="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="clickSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>        
  </div>
 </div>     

 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/BM3j0HMMLUHHBSSFZDXX?p=preview